# How do I convert a list of strings to integers in Python

Tags: python, list, integer

I need help on how to convert a list to integers, for example

```
lst = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Desired output:

```
123
```

I think I explain myself, I do not speak English so I use a translator, I hope it is understood.

Comment: Please post the code that's failing, and the actual output.

Comment: Not accepting answers, so here it is in a comment: `from functools import reduce;
print(reduce(lambda a,b: 10*a+b, map(int,["1","2","3"])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things: 1. concatenate the elements of the array together into a single string, and 2. convert that string to a number.

You can do #1 with the `join` string method. Normally, you call `join` on some other string that you want to put in between the ones you're joining, but since you don't want one of those here, you can just use the empty string:

```
>>> lst=["1","2","3"]
>>> "".join(lst)
'123'
```

Since that's still a string, not a numeric value, this is where step 2 comes in. You can convert it to an integer with the `int` function:

```
>>> int("".join(lst))
123
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the strings, then convert to an integer:

```
int(''.join(lst))
```

The alternative of converting to integer and then joining is much more complicated, and will drop any leading zeros you have:

```
from math import floor, log10

result = 0
for x in lst:
    n = int(x)
    result *= 10**((x and floor(log10(x))) + 1)
    result += n
```

Because of how Python's `and` operator works, the expression `x and ...` returns `x` immediately if it is zero, and the right hand side if not, which is what you want when taking logarithms.